# Install IIS Manager in Windows 7 Home Basic

Tags: .net, iis, windows-7

I have 64 bit windows 7.I installed IIS 8.0  Express on My M/c. But I am not able to see

1. IIS Manager
2. LocalHost
3. Some of the IIS features were not Present there

What Should I DO?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Home Basic edition does not have the full IIS, so no way to have IIS Manager installed.

Of course, you can use IIS Express. If you do want to manage IIS Express, you can use [Jexus Manager for IIS Express](https://jexusmanager.com).